# 3 ошибки/предупреждения в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Доброго времени суток. Начал осваивать Android Studio и Java. Решил для начала создать простейшую программу. Есть 3 поля. В 2 из них вводятся числа. В 3 поле выводится их сумма по нажатию на кнопку. 
Ошибки на скринах внизу. Объясните кто-нибудь пожалуйста в чём суть ошибок и пути их исправления.

```
  package com.example.admin.test;

      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void onButtonClick (View v) {
    EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
    EditText el2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    TextView resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);
    int number1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
    int number2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
    int res = number1 + number2;
    resText.setText(Integer.toString(res));
}
```

}

[image: Ошибка1. Casting findViewById(R.id.num2) to EditText is redundant]
[image: Ошибка2. Method ... is never used. Вроде как не ошибка, а предупреждение, что нигде не используется(?!)]
[image: Ошибка3. Number formatting does not take into account locale settings. Consider using String.format instead..]

Comment: (не по теме) При установке выдавало сообщение "c++ include". А что даёт это подключение? Использование с++ именно  при написании кода или как?

Comment: попробуйте игнорировать то, что говорит вам студия, и собрать проект. Если не соберется, тогда покажите вывод окошечка `run`, там будет необходимая информация для того, чтобы помочь вам. Про `c++ include` - вероятно, студия предлагала вам возможность использования `NDK`. Это не совсем использование `c++` в проекте, там немного сложнее. Можете почитать про `NDK` в интернете.

Comment: дело в том, что проект не собирается, выдаёт другую ошибку( в комментарии под ответом). И даже если соберётся, то нужно сгенерировать apk, ибо процессор не поддерживает ни один из эмуляторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я все же правильно понял, то вы спрашиваете не про то, почему у вас красным выделено `R` (иногда студия показывает, что там ошибка, но фиксится обновлением `gradle-refresh`-ем, или просто перекомпиляцией).

Что касается этих трех - это не ошибки. Это предупреждения. Те, что подчеркнуты серым - просто предупреждения. Обычно такие же предупреждения выдает компилятор при компиляции. Выделенные желтым - умные предупреждения самой студии.

Сообщение, которое вы видите для каждого предупреждения, содержит необходимую вам информацию:

1. Нет необходимости в явном приведении. Это значит, что вы можете просто убрать `(EditText)` скобочку. Кстати, если вы поставите курсор на подчеркнутый текст и нажмете <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то студия предложит вам варианты разрешения данной ситуации, и в этом случае просто предложит удалить скобочку.
2. Функция никогда не используется. Это значит, что студия не зарегистрировала мест, в которых эта функция используется, и значит, вероятно, эта функция бесполезна.
3. Умное предупреждение студии, по сути сразу говорит, что такое форматирование не принимает во внимание настройки локали. И сразу же предлагает лучшую альтернативу - использование `String.format` (кстати, можете просто записать как `res + ""` - тоже приведение к строке).

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Но при сборка не получается из-за ошибки, которая мне неизвестна, можете и с этим помочь?)

Error:error: '59' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'59' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].

Comment: ошибка вроде в этой строке, но другое число не подходит...
        android:layout_height="59"

Comment: @Андрей в ошибке же вроде понятно написано) напишите там вместо вашего 59 либо `"match_parent"`, либо `"wrap_content"` - первое подгоняет размер под размер родителя, второе подгоняет размер таким образом, чтобы размер был минимальным, но в него помещался контент. Я думаю, вам нужно первое.

Comment: ооой, я не понял) Только-только изучать начал, прошу извинить. Спасибо огромное, всё заработало

Comment: @Андрей в качестве параметра размера нельзя указать просто число (как 59), нужна его размерность (dp, px и др.) - android:layout_height="59dp"